# About "no prevously-included files" warnings when installing packages

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Most of the time when i build a package or install libraries using pip I see such warnings in the log.

```
warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found under directory 'tests'
```

I read in many places that these warning do not affect an ongoing installation but since any sort of warning is undesirable I would like to know why these appear. These persist even in virtualenvs.